# Magento 2 - If I load a category then I get redirected to search result site

Tags: magento2, category

I created a new store view.

I have a category called "T-Shirts".

If I load that category e.g. [www.new-store-view.example.com/shirts](http://www.new-store-view.example.com/shirts) then it loads the search site showing results for "shirts" instead of loading the category site.

I already tried `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is 2 way to implement:

1. Create the observer to the event `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view` and handle it like

   ```php
   <?php
   declare(strict_types=1);

   namespace Acme\StackExchange\Observer\Frontend\Catalog;

   use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;
   use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as RequestHttp;
   use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
   use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
   use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
   use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

   class CategoryViewPreDispatch implements ObserverInterface
   {
       protected ActionFlag                  $actionFlag;
       protected StoreManagerInterface       $storeManager;
       protected UrlInterface                $urlBuilder;
       protected CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository;

       public function __construct(
           ActionFlag $actionFlag,
           StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
           UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
           CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
       ) {
           $this->actionFlag         = $actionFlag;
           $this->storeManager       = $storeManager;
           $this->urlBuilder         = $urlBuilder;
           $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
       }

       /**
        * @inheritDoc
        */
       public function execute(Observer $observer)
       {
           return;

           /** @var RequestHttp $request */
           $request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('request');
           /** @var ActionInterface $action */
           $action = $observer->getEvent()->getData('controller_action');

           $categoryId = $request->getParam('id', false);
           if (!$categoryId) {
               return;
           }

           try {
               $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
           } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
               return;
           }

           // any checks if needed like
           if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
               return;
           }

           $action->getResponse()->setRedirect(
               $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                   'catalogsearch/result/',
                   [
                       '_query' => [
                           'q' => $category->getName(),
                       ],
                   ]
               )
           );
           $this->actionFlag->set('', $action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
           $this->actionFlag->set('', $action::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH, true);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create the observer to the event `catalog_controller_category_init_after` and handle it like

   ```php
   <?php
   declare(strict_types=1);

   namespace Acme\StackExchange\Observer\Frontend\Catalog;

   use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
   use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
   use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
   use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

   class CategoryControllerInitAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
   {
       protected UrlInterface $urlBuilder;

       public function __construct(UrlInterface $urlBuilder)
       {
           $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
       }


       /**
        * @inheritDoc
        */
       public function execute(Observer $observer)
       {
           /** @var Category $category */
           $category = $observer->getEvent()->getData('category');
           /** @var ActionInterface $action */
           $action = $observer->getEvent()->getData('controller_action');

           // any checks if needed like
           if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
               return;
           }

           $action->getResponse()->setRedirect(
               $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                   'catalogsearch/result/',
                   [
                       '_query' => [
                           'q' => $category->getName(),
                       ],
                   ]
               )
           );

           // this message will be logged
           throw new LocalizedException(__('Redirect to search result'));
       }
   }
   ```

   **NOTE:** The exception message will be logged in log